# ASP.Net MVC "mini spas" and Angularjs Routing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is happening with routing in MVC and Angularjs.  I am seeing different behavior between the 1.0.x version of Angularjs and the 1.3.x version.

I am building an MVC site with multiple "mini spas".  I have an MVC controller called Registration and the route to it is http://mysite/Registration.  The index view for that controller then renders a page containing the html and angular scripts.

I want to have angular routes that will render html templates and have set up the routing as follows.

```
// this works in 1.0.x
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", []);

registrationModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Members', { 
            templateUrl: '/templates/members.html', 
            controller: 'MembersController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Updates', { 
            templateUrl: '/templates/updates.html', 
            controller: 'UpdatesController' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

When I have the above routing and reference angularjs 1.0.x everything work as I would expect.  The views load correctly and it does not post back to the server for the /Registration/* routes.

However, when I reference angular 1.3.x and have the following routing:

```
// this does not work in 1.3.x
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", ['ngRoute']);

registrationModule.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Members', { 
            templateUrl: '/templates/members.html', 
            controller: 'MembersController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Updates', { 
            templateUrl: '/templates/updates.html', 
            controller: 'UpdatesController' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

The views do not load on the /Registration/* routes and it posts back to the server for the RegistrationController to handle all /Registration/* routes.

Is there some fundamental difference in routing between the versions?  Have I failed to implement angular routing correctly in the new version?

Comment: Have you referenced the additional JS file for the routing module? Also, do you see any errors being output in the console in the browser?

Comment: @mojo722 did you find an answer for this?